# How to add uigesturerecognizer to UIDocumentInteractionController Preview?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uidocumentinteraction

Is it possible to add gesture recogniser to `UIDocumentInteractionController`? Right now I am not able to add anything on `UIDocumentInteractionController` preview. Please help how to add gesture recogniser or even a button on top of `UIDocumentInteraction` controller?

Comment: u can't add gesture in UIDocumentInteractionController

Comment: @nitinkachhadiya Can you please suggest me any other alternative because i have opened keynotes, numbers, pages file's in UIDocumentInteractionController & required to add gesture on UIDocumentInteractionController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the apple documentation for UIDocumentInteractionController [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

They are also providing an example for add gesture recognizers to UIDocumentInteractionController.. See the [link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Listings/Classes_DITableViewController_m.html)..

Comment: I believe, in that example, the gesture recognizer is added to the cell's image view, rather than the UIDocumentInteractionController's view, as per the question. I am confused how is this answer is accepted. Am I missing something?